# Java-EE-6: How to store a boolean in a @ManyToMany and @ManyToOne relationships?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, relationship, relation

I am working on a data model that basically consists of users and documents. Now everytime a new document is added, there should be a flag that identifies a document as "unseen" as long as the particular user did not had a look at it (e.g. clicked on it).

How would you model such a scenario ? Is there somehow a way to attach a boolean/flag to the relationship between users and documents ?

Here's my simplified model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @Column(length = 128)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<Document>();

    // getters and setters ...

}
```

Here's the document class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Document")
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "Inbox", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    protected List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    // getters and setters ...

}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You seem to need an additional column in your join table, viewed. Hence, you will need to split your many-to-many into two one-to-many/many-to-one relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers! I'll try your suggestions and come back as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer by JB Nizet that Matt made reference to the join table has a unique primary key (`id`), one unique constraint on the two foreign keys and an additional column. This is a good way to go.

But as you are useing `@ManyToMany` you are most likely to have a primary key which consists of two foreign keys in the join table. In case you'll want to stay with that pattern and add an extra `viewed` column, you will most likely need to get accustomed to using `@Embeddable` classes to have the composite primary key reflected in your `@Entity`. Remember, when you do it like this, you will need to override `equals`/`hashcode`.

You can see [my answer on the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890739/jsf2-0-jpa-how-to-set-list-element-mapped-in-onetomany/14891888#14891888) as a staring point to creating your `@Entity` classes. In the answer the entity from the joined table is described, as well as its primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column to your `Inbox` join table stores the "unseen" boolean. Then [map the join table as new entity, and decompose the many-to-many association into two OneToMany associations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127262/139010).